# How to include files and folders with 7zip powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

Im trying to make my powershell script zip up a few files and folders.  At the moment I can make my script either zip all files (with no folders included), or zip all files with folders included but to the wrong path.
An example would be if I have a folder named wordpress with files and a few subfolders.  I need my zip file to be wordpress.zip, with all files and subfolders being in the root of that zip as opposed to \wordpress\files.*

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code so far

```
function create-7zip([String] $aDirectory, [String] $aZipfile){
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZipfile", "$aDirectory";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
}

create-7zip "$storageDir\wordpress\*.*"  "$storageDir\wordpress.zip"
```

The above example will only zip files inside of my target folder, I need it to include the subfolders as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
create-7zip "$storageDir\wordpress\*"  "$storageDir\wordpress.zip"
```

will include files and subfolders.

Comment: This was exactly the solution.  Thank you for your reply.